# Unable to use Wake On Lan on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wake-on-lan

I turned my old dell inspiron 3650 into a ubuntu server. I am trying to remote boot it with wake on lan, but it is not working. I have tried to add port 9 to the ufw firewall, and I have also have the wake on lan setting in bios on, and my deep sleep control is set to only s5. I use the command `systemctl suspend` to put my computer to sleep, but the network adapter does not light up orange. At this point wake on lan or ssh clients do not work.

Comment: Maybe you need S3 sleep and not S5? https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000146067/newer-dell-system-models-will-not-wake-on-lan-with-deep-sleep-control-set-to-s5-in-the-windows

Comment: The current status of the NIC (say eth0, change it) (which is in addition of the ability for the NIC to wake the motherboard) can be seen using `ethtool eth0` with the outputs `Supports Wake-on:` and `Wake-on:` . While ethtool can change it, it's probably an other system part (systemd, NetworkManager etc.) that sets it when the system goes to sleep. Also I was talking about sleeping. I'm not sure how it works from boot.